# Unable to make opengl texture working properly

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw a simple cube with vbos. But when I run my program I dont get the expected result. Whereas being textured, my cube is fully opaque with one color of my texture...

You can see below my code :

loading of the texture with SFML:

```
void Grass::load() {
    sf::Image texture;

    if (!texture.loadFromFile(path_m))
        std::cerr << "Error while loading texture : " << path_m << std::endl;
    else {
        glGenTextures(1, &id_m);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_m);
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.getSize().x,
                    texture.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    texture.getPixelsPtr());

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
}
```

Generation of the vertices of the cube:

```
void Chunck::generate() {

    {
        std::vector vec = { -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // Face 1
                -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,     // Face 1

                1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,       // Face 2
                1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,         // Face 2

                -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,      // Face 3
                -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    // Face 3

                -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,        // Face 4
                -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,        // Face 4

                -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     // Face 5
                -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     // Face 5

                -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,         // Face 6
                -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0 };     // Face 6
        vertices_m.insert(vertices_m.begin(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
    }

    {
        std::vector vec = {0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 1
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 1

                0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 2
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 2

                0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 3
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 3

                0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 4
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 4

                0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 5
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 5

                0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 6
                0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1};    // Face 6
        texture_m.insert(texture_m.begin(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
    }
}
```

Cube Drawing:

```
void Chunck::draw() const {

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_m);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(vertices_m.size() * sizeof(double)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassTexture_m.getID());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices_m.size());
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Load of the cube into VBO:

```
void Chunck::load() {
    grassTexture_m.load();

    if (glIsBuffer(vboID_m) == GL_TRUE)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboID_m);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID_m);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_m);
    {
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vertices_m.size() + texture_m.size()) * sizeof(float), 0,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices_m.size() * sizeof(float), vertices_m.data());
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_m.size() * sizeof(float),
                texture_m.size() * sizeof(float), texture_m.data());
    }
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}
```

Comment: If the data type of your vertex coordinate array is `double`, then it has to be `sizeof(double)` and `GL_DOUBLE`, instead of `sizeof(float)` and `GL_FLOAT`. But if the data type is `float`, then it has to be `BUFFER_OFFSET(vertices_m.size() * sizeof(float))`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, effectively this is wrong, it should be sizeof(float). But it doesn't solved my problem

Comment: where do you install the shader program object ([`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml))?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have add a shader to my program, and now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The data type of the vertices is `float`, so the buffer offset is `BUFFER_OFFSET(vertices_m.size() * sizeof(float))`, instead of `sizeof(double)`.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(
    2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(vertices_m.size() * sizeof(float)));
```

Are you sure that the attribute index of the texture coordinates is *2* ? Note, the vertex attribute index can be set by [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index) (`layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;`) or it can be get by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml)
from the shader program object.

The 3rd parameter of [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) is the number of the vertices, but not the number of elements in the array:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices_m.size() / 3);
```

Further I recommend to enable the [Depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test), before drawing the geometry. Since the default depth function is `GL_LESS`, this causes that the geometry which is closer to the view position covers the geometry behind it.

```
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
```

Comment: "The 3rd parameter of glDrawArrays is the number of primitives and not the number of vertices" ITYM "... is the number of vertices, not the number of total floats in the array".